# Can't retrieve intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a main activity with a recyclerview that contains images inside imageviews. When you click on an image, a detail activity is launched.

I need to pass 2 objects to an intent and retrieve them in the detail activity, but for some reason I can't do it. When I use a debugger, I can see that both objects are saved in the intent extras.

However, when I fetch them on the other side, I can't find my arraylist extra.

Can you help me to figure out why?

This is my code:

```
holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mActivity.isTwoPaneMode()) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putParcelable(MovieListActivity.MOVIE,movie);
            arguments.putStringArrayList("TRAILERS", (ArrayList)movie.getTrailerList());
            MovieDetailFragment fragment = new MovieDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.movie_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        } else {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MovieListActivity.MOVIE, movie);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("TRAILERS", (ArrayList)movie.getTrailerList());

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

On the other activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            ArrayList<String> trailers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("TRAILERS");
            Movie movie = intent.getParcelableExtra(MovieListActivity.MOVIE);
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

            arguments.putParcelable(MovieListActivity.MOVIE, movie);

            arguments.putStringArrayList(MovieListActivity.MOVIE,
                    getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("TRAILERS"));

            MovieDetailFragment fragment = new MovieDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.movie_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    }
```

My movie class implements parcelable correctly.

Comment: are you sure its your activity and not your fragment? if you debug inside the activity does it get the items correctly?

Comment: I am debugging where I put the values (The callback in my movieAdapter class) and in the detail activity. I didn't debug it on the fragment

Comment: Is there anything in the intent on the caller side? May be `movie.getTrailerList()` returns empty or null object?

Comment: Actually, after adding the objects to the intent, I checked the debugger and I could see that none of the objects is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Android Intent docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).

Specifically, the `The name must include a package prefix, ...` when using Intent#putStringArrayListExtra.

Try something like this:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(PACKAGE_NAME + ".TRAILERS", (ArrayList)movie.getTrailerList());
```

where PACKAGE_NAME is equal to your application's package name.

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching data from a `Bundle` instead of and `Intent`. This way you can know if data was actually passed to the activity because the `Bundle` will be `null` if nothing was passed. Also add the package name to the data String.

`PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();`

`arguments.putStringArrayList(PACKAGE_NAME+"TRAILERS,(ArrayList)movie.getTrailerList());`

Instead of doing:
`Intent intent = getIntent();
     ArrayList<String> trailers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(PACKAGE_NAME+"TRAILERS");`

do:

    `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<String> trailers;
    if(extras!=null){
        ArrayList<String> trailers = extras.getStringArrayList("TRAILERS");
    }else{
        Toast.makeToast(this, "No data was passed",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }`

If the Toast shows up it means your data wasn't passed correctly.